# apigility - What alternatives I can use for Zend\Paginator\Paginator in Collections?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, paginator

In several endpoints I'm doing with Apigility, I want retrieve all the possible results without pagination. Is there a class to replace Paginator in Collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To receive a response in `Hal` without pagination you should simply return an `array` from your queries instead of an instance of `Zend\Paginator\Paginator`.

Comment: So, is it better ignore the EndpointCollection class instead of change the extends class?

Answer (score -2):

For those who happen to find this question just as I did. You can edit the number of items per page in the module.config.php file. It's set as the value "page_size". Changing it to a number larger than the total amount in your collection will let you receive all the results in one page.
Admittedly not the cleanest of solutions, but it worked for me.